# How do I make a map using a struct in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct, using

what I am trying to do is use C++ struct to make a simple map.

for example,

if I have

```
struct Map { char name; int age };
Map MapObj[] = { {'charles', 10}, {'kate', 20}, {'nate', 10} }
```

how can I access to kate's age using the map?
I tried MapjObj['kate'] but it does not work.
How can I access the age using the name?

Comment: I mean the simplest way would be to internally use a `std::map` but assuming you're trying to make your own for whatever reason, you would need to know about overloading operators - specifically, `operator[]`. You can find the interface of `std::map` online and you would just need to mimic it

Comment: A "simple map" is usually implemented through a [hash map](https://medium.com/@aozturk/simple-hash-map-hash-table-implementation-in-c-931965904250). What you are missing is that we use an algorithm knows as *Hash Function* to encode the string into a unique index position in the array.

Comment: Are you implementing a red/black tree or a B-Tree or something similar?

Comment: *but it does not work* -- Please be more specific.  The code doesn't compile?  Doesn't run?.

Comment: You need to study more about the basics of C++. Learn the difference between single characters and strings, single-quotes and double-quotes.

Comment: `char name;` I don't think you want that either. A string in `c++` is `std::strimg` a `char` is a single character. like `a`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<algorithm>` facilities C++ offers, and specifically - [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find); something like:

```
auto pos = std::find(
    std::begin(MapOjb), 
    std::end(MapObj),
    [](const Map& m) { return m == "kate"}
);
```

But note that:

1. `name` must be an `std::string` or a `char *` (in the latter case, you would use `strcmp()`, not plain string comparison).
2. `Map` and `MapObj` are incredibly poor choices for names here...

Pass it the beginning and the end of the array you created, as well as a lambda function.

Comment: You can use `std::size()` to get the element count of many standard containers, including fixed arrays: `std::find(MapOjb, MapOjb + std::size(MapObj), ...)` Better, you can use `std:begin()`/`std::end()` instead, which have been specialized for many containers, including fixed arrays: `std::find(std::begin(MapOjb), std::end(MapOjb), ...)`

Comment: I have my doubts about whether someone who is still at the figure-out-the-difference-between-chars-and-strings stage is going to grok `<algorithm>` well.... an explicit manually-written lookup function (i.e. using a for-loop) might be good to add as an alternate solution that is easier to understand.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Hmm, good to know. I've gotten used to just using a span over the raw array, or creating an `std::array` to begin with.